# Swipe Gesture UIImageView in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I can't seem to get my swipe gesture recognizer to work for an image view inside of a table view cell.

I have confirmed that images.count > 1.

```
if images.count > 0 {
                let imageUrlString = images[0] as String
                let imageUrl = NSURL(string: imageUrlString)
                imageCell.cellImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(imageUrl, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"))

                if images.count > 1 {
                    let swipeRightGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeRight))
                    swipeRightGestureRecognizer.direction = .Right
                    imageCell.cellImageView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRightGestureRecognizer)

                    let swipeLeftGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeLeft))
                    swipeLeftGestureRecognizer.direction = .Left
                    imageCell.cellImageView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeftGestureRecognizer)
                }
            } else {
                imageCell.cellImageView.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")
            }
```

swipeLeft and swipeRight

```
func swipeLeft(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        imageView = sender.view as! UIImageView

        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight
        imageView.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: nil)

        if imageIndex == images.count - 1 {
            let urlString = images[0] as String
            let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
            imageView.sd_setImageWithURL(url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"))

            imageIndex = 0

        } else {
            let urlString = images[imageIndex + 1] as String
            let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
            imageView.sd_setImageWithURL(url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"))

            imageIndex += 1
        }
    }

    func swipeRight(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        imageView = sender.view as! UIImageView

        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft
        imageView.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: nil)

        if imageIndex == 0 {
            let urlString = images.last! as String
            let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
            imageView.sd_setImageWithURL(url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"))

            imageIndex = images.count - 1

        } else {
            let urlString = images[imageIndex - 1] as String
            let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
            imageView.sd_setImageWithURL(url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"))

            imageIndex -= 1
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// imageview defaultly userinteractionenable property set as  false, so u need to set it as userinteractionenable = true

```
imageCell.cellImageView.userInteractionEnabled =true
```